# B-Bone not displaying as box but instead displaying as sticks

Tags: armature, bones

I'm having a bit of difficulty with armature displays.

I've selected B-Bone as the display which I know is supposed to make bones look like boxes but instead they're appearing very thin like the stick display. I thought it was because I somehow accidentally re-sized the thickness of the bones so I tried tampering with it with ctrl + alt + s and such but that didn't seem to work. Here's an image of how it looks.

[image]

If I could get any sort of help that would be great! Thank you all in advance.

[edit]

here's the .blend file

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> works, it's just that your bones are very very thin, so scale several times.

Comment: looks like the bones were extremely thin that I had to scale it a _bunch_ of times for them to look thicker. this solved my problem thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have scaled them down to absolutely zero you will see just a simple line and there is no way to get back and you should redo everything from the beginning.